# BingPreview user agent

Tags: bing, web-crawlers, user-agent, botattack

I'm getting several invalid requests from a "BingPreview" user agent. The complete user agent header is: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534+ (KHTML, like Gecko) BingPreview/1.0b`

The invalid requests seem to come from a bug in the HTML parser in the crawler, which ends up generating invalid URLs.

Is this user agent legit, really related to Bing? Or is it yet another fraud?

Comment: According to ip2location.com, the IP (157.55.112.206) does belong to Microsoft... are they really using AppleWebKit??

Comment: Looks like you uncovered a new feature of Bing.

Comment: does this still appear? If so, it's probably not actually Bing since they still haven't set up preview renders.

Answer (score 3):

I realize that this is an old post but after researching this I came upon an article explaining the purpose of this user agent.

In this article they explain that this is a user agent string used to fetch images in real time when being accessed through the Bing app. Meaning as you scroll through pictures within this app you may end up clicking on one to bring up a full screen view. When you do this the user agent string is used to make a request to your site to get the latest version of the image.

(Blog post about BingPreview)
http://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2012/10/26/page-snapshots-in-bing-windows-8-app-to-bring-new-crawl-traffic-to-sites/

[image: Screenshot from Bing Webmaster Tools explaining the nature of BingPreview]

Answer (score 1):

They may be testing full page previews in search results similar to Google's. When you preview your page in Google you get a hit from one of their IP's. Bing right now just has a snippet of information and may be working on a full preview of the web page